# Passing property value using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier with storyboards

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Apologies if my terminology is a bit off, new to objective C!
I am trying to pass a value from one UIViewController class to another. I am using storyboards. I am able to display the second ViewController using the following code:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FormView"];
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

That works fine. In my second ViewController's (FormView) header file I set a property like so:

```
@interface FormController : UIViewController {
NSString *selectedBooking;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedBooking;
@end
```

How do I "pass the value" from my first Controller to the second Controller? As far as I understand I have to set the property like so:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FormView"];
vc.selectedBooking = @"test";
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Which gives me the error: Property 'selectedBooking' not found on object of type 'UIViewController'.

What is the correct way to set the property? Is there something else I should be using rather that instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to cast it.

i.e.

```
FormController *fc = (FormController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FormView"];
fc.selectedBooking = @"test";
[self presentModalViewController:fc animated:YES];
```

then the rest of your code will work :D

Answer (score 2):

Just in case if you do not wish to import the class `FormController` and go with it you can do as follow. really very handy:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = ..
UIViewController *vc = ...
```

> [vc setvalue:@"test" ForKey:@"selectedBooking"]; //using KVC

```
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

NOTE: This will only work with properties.