# unrecognized selector sent to instance on ios table view cell click

Tags: ios, storyboard, unrecognized-selector

I'm a very beginner to iOs. I'm going to view a list in table view controller. My application is a story board application. I did the following code to go to the next view.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   LawyerViewController *dvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LawyerViewController"];
   dvc.lawyer = @"Thisara";//[self.myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
}
```

in my `LawyerViewController` header file I defined the following property.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lawyer;
```

When I'm clicking on the cell, I've got following error.

```
2014-07-26 23:56:14.420 lawyerapp[3626:60b] -[UIViewController setLawyer:]: unrecognized        selector sent to instance 0x8cdd1f0
2014-07-26 23:56:14.424 lawyerapp[3626:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setLawyer:]:      
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8cdd1f0'
```

How do I fix this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I can see a connection with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709117/passing-property-value-using-instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier-with-storyb

Comment: UIViewController does not have a method named `setLawyer`.  (And it would pretty scary if view controllers started getting their own lawyers.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not defined the class in `storyBoard`.

**Go to your `viewController` in StoryBoard ->
 than `identity Inspector` -> class -> Put the class `LawyerViewController`.**

[image]
Clean,build and run